# set parameters to ejb timer task to perform backend process

Tags: java, ejb-3.1, timertask

I used `EJB Timer` task to perform my periodic service query to `database` and send the update to client within specific period. This period is defined by client.

I pass the client `request` to the `ejb` `timer` `stateless` `session bean`. The `request` is stored as a `instance variable`.

When I call timer task through JNDI I set the client request to this `instance variable` and its available before `timerService.createTimer()` call. But when the @Timeout happen the `instance variable` is `null`.

I need this client request to perform DB query to find request parameters.

```
@Stateless
public class PeriodicService implements TimerRemote{

   @Override
   public void initializeTimer(Date firstDate, long timeout, String info) throws RemoteException {
    try {   
             // below line show the request is not null.
        System.out.println("request in initializeTimer "+this.request);

       // create onetime service now.
        timerService.createTimer(firstDate, info); 
        log.info("Timer created at " +  firstDate + " with info: " + info);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        log.fatal("Exception after create timer : "+ e.toString()); 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

      @Timeout
  public void ejbTimeout(Timer arg0) {
    // below line show the requst as null
    log.debug("Request in ejbTimeout "+this.request);

  }

    public void setRequest(IVEFRequest request) {
       this.request = request;
   }


   private      IVEFRequest     request         = null;


 }
```

I'm new to `EJB`. Some thing wrong the way I do it? or how can I keep the request variable available until I `cancel/stop` the `timer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code, no need to create a separate instance variable.

Provide the object that you would like to receive in timeout method while creating timer.

```
timerService.createTimer(firstDate, request);
```

Then, fetch the object in timeout method which was passed at timer creation.

```
(IVEFRequest)arg0.getInfo();
```

Comment: how can I cancel the timer then? I used the info part to identify the timer. But if I use that to pass the request then how can I cancel the timer when I want to cancel it?

Comment: @user2771655 Can't you identify from request object itself which one to cancel, if not then add required information to it. Else It can hold any object type. So you can add request+info in Map & pass it, then you can have both.